# Passing array between phtml files returns warning in system.log

Tags: magento-1.9, phtml, array, system.log

I've been searching and reading about passing data between phtml files in the last couple of hours but I haven't find a solution to my problem.

I'm passing an array with a product object and a category names array, like this:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list')->assign(array("_product"=>$_item,"_categ_names"=>$categs_names))->setTemplate('catalog/product/view/type/product_listing.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

from related.phtml . The data passed is displayed correctly and everything is alright, except the fact that for every product sent/displayed a warning appears in system.log:

```
Warning: addcslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given  in ...\trunk\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php on line 296
```

There are no type checks in lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php for arrays, only for *int* and *float*, and then the *addcslashes* function is called.

```
protected function _quote($value)
{
    if (is_int($value) || is_float($value)) {
        return $value;
    }
    // Fix for null-byte injection
    $value = addcslashes($value, "\000\032");
    $this->_connect();
    return $this->_connection->quote($value);
}
```

I've tried to pass data with different functions, like *setData*, *assign* or dirrectly in *createBlock*, but the behaviour is the same.

The weird thing is that in *createBlock* function can be passed arrays, as seen here:

```
public function createBlock($type, $name='', array $attributes = array())
```

and then added with:

```
->addData($attributes);
```

but the same warning appears.

**Edited, with code for product_listing.phtml:**

```
<?php  
$_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
?>
<a 
  href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"
  title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product,   'small_image'), null, true) ?>"
  class="product-image text-center">
    <img
        class="img-responsive"
        src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(280); ?>"
        width="280"
        height="280"
        alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
</a>
<h2 class="product-name">
<a 
    href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"
    title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
        <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name'); ?>
</a>
</h2>
<?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($_product->getPrice() == 0 && in_array("Etichete electronice",$_categ_names)):?>
<p class="special-price-text"><?php echo __("Pret personalizat");?></p>   
<?php else: ?>
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php if($_product->getPrice() > $_product->getFinalPrice()): ?>
<div class="sales_icon_wrapper">
    <span class="sales_icon"><?php echo $this->__('Promo') ?> %</span>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="actions">
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <?php if($_product->getPrice() == 0 && in_array("Etichete electronice",$_categ_names)):?>
        <a href="/contact" title="<?php echo $this->__('Solicita oferta') ?>" class="button btn-cart btn btn-primary"><?php echo $this->__('Solicita oferta') ?></a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Order')) ?>" class="button btn-cart btn btn-primary" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><?php echo $this->__('Order') ?></button>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php else: ?>
    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Has anyone encountered the same problem or is it just me? Can anyone help me solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add your code for product_listing.phtml

Comment: @JaiminSutariya , I've added the code for product_listing.phtml.

Comment: @MelaniaJitaru did you find a fix for this? I'm experiencing the same issue

Comment: @RickyOdinMatthews Yes, I did. I actually found that the problem was not with how the data was passed to the other template or what functions were used. I tracked the problem to the 'Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List.php' block, at line 74, where the categoryId was set with '$categories->getIterator()', which is in fact an object, thus, the error. I've extended the block and passed the category entity_id as categoryId.

Comment: could you please share the solution, as answer, ty

Comment: @MelaniaJitaru did you fix this?

Comment: @JaiminSutariya u managed to fix it?

Comment: @MerGh, Sorry but I did not find any solution to this but as OP stated in the comment, he has found the solution to the problem.